# Why do these passwords with the same salt and encryption not have the same output?

Tags: python, cryptography, base64

The output of the 2 variables "x" and "l" should be the same as they use the exact same salt and encrypting process.

I'd like some info on why it is not the same and how I can fix it for a simple login algorithm.

Code:

```py
import os
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
import base64


def encrypt_password(password, salt=None):
    # Create a password hash
    if not salt:
        salt = os.urandom(64)
        print("...")
        token = base64.b64encode(salt).decode('utf-8')



    password = password.encode()
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256,
        iterations=100000,
        length=32,
        salt=salt,
        backend=default_backend()
    )
    key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))
    # Encrypt the password
    f = Fernet(key)
    encrypted_password = f.encrypt(password)
    return encrypted_password, salt

x, salt2 = encrypt_password("Hello")
print(x)

l, salt1 = encrypt_password("Hello", salt2)
print(l)

print(salt1 == salt2)
```

I've checked the salts like 20 times and I'm almost certain they don't change during any of the process. All I can think of is that there is something I don't know about any of the libraries used in the process that are inconsistent.

Comment: I fixed the answer below, it should work now!

Comment: Your new answer makes no sense, it would break the entire program and not encrypt the password in the first place.

Comment: I want to note that the entire thing is incredibly odd, why are you encrypting a password using a key which is a KDF derived from that password? It makes no sense.

Comment: What makes you think they should be the same? The documentation makes it sound like they shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encrypted Passwords are not deterministically the same with this encryption method.

This can be proven if we put the input `salt` to a constant.

Everytime you run the code the generated `encrypted_password` will differ.
In the example bellow our input `salt1 = b"abc"` stays the same. The generated passwords are different. This encryption method is **not** suitable for deterministic key generation.

```
import base64
import os

from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC


def encrypt_password(password, salt=None):
    # Create a password hash
    if not salt:
        salt = os.urandom(64)
        print("...")
        token = base64.b64encode(salt).decode('utf-8')

    password = password.encode()
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256,
        iterations=100000,
        length=32,
        salt=salt,
        backend=default_backend()
    )
    key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))
    # Encrypt the password
    f = Fernet(key)
    encrypted_password = f.encrypt(password)
    return encrypted_password, salt


salt1 = b"abc"
x, salt2 = encrypt_password("Hello", salt1)
print(x)

y, salt3 = encrypt_password("Hello", salt1)
print(y)
print(x == y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Fernet tokens are not stable for two reason:

1. Fernet supports token expiration, which it handles by embedding the current time (as a 64 bits unsigned integer) in the token, as documented:

   > The encrypted message contains the current time when it was generated in plaintext, the time a message was created will therefore be visible to a possible attacker.
2. Fernet uses CBC internally, CBC encryption needs a key, a plaintext, *and an initialisation vector*, for security Fernet always generates the IV on its own internally then embeds that in the token.

So even if you create Fernet tokens within the same second (or use `encrypt_at_time` to fix it), the content is randomised via the IV which you  are not given any control over. By design, you can not reasonably get the same token twice out of Fernet, even if you provide the same key, data, and fixed creation time.

Comment: Maybe link to the token spec: https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md#token-format

Comment: Technically the spec would not preclude an implementation from taking in an IV (that would make sense e.g. for an implementation targeted towards µc which wouldn't have a cross-platform way to generate random data). [The cryptography doc](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#implementation) might be a better source in that it mentions "Initialization vectors are generated using `os.urandom()`" and none of the functions allows passing one in, but you mostly read the information in negative.

Comment: Well I think it's useful to see what a token contains. And about the IV it says *"the IV must be chosen uniquely for every token"*.